# Laravel 5.5 PersonalAccessToken table new column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-passport

I ve managed to add a new column into `oauth_access_tokens` table called `callback_url`. The problem i ve got is when i am trying to pass `callback_url` value into `createToken` function.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validation->make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'scopes' => 'array|in:'.implode(',', Passport::scopeIds()),
    ])->validate();

    return $request->user()->createToken(
        $request->name, $request->callback_url, $request->scopes ?: []
    );
}
```

VUEJS COMPONENT:

```
store() {
            this.accessToken = null;

            this.form.errors = [];

            axios.post('/user/token', this.form)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.form.name = '';
                        this.form.callback_url = '';
                        this.form.scopes = [];
                        this.form.errors = [];

                        this.tokens.push(response.data.token);

                        this.showAccessToken(response.data.accessToken);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        if (typeof error.response.data === 'object') {
                            this.form.errors = _.flatten(_.toArray(error.response.data));
                        } else {
                            this.form.errors = ['Something went wrong. Please try again.'];
                        }
                    });
        },
```

It works fine without $request->callback_url but with that extra parameter this is an error i am getting back.

> Whoops! Something went wrong!
>
> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Models\User::createToken() must be of
>   the type array, string given, called in UserAccessTokenController.php
>   on line 62
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError/vendor/laravel/passport/src/HasApiTokens.php
>   64 { "file": "/UserAccessTokenController.php", "line": 62, "function":
>   "createToken", "class": "Models\User", "type": "->" } { "function":
>   "store", "class": "UserAccessTokenController", "type": "->" }

Did anyone had that issue or know how to deal with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function *createToken()* accepts only two parameters. I solve my problem by creating a *accessToken* then updating a result with new *callback_url* value. Hope that helps.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $token = $request->user()->createToken(
        $request->name, $request->scopes ?: []
    );

    if ($request->callback_url){

        $url = $request->callback_url;

        $request->user()->tokens()->where( 'id', $token->token->id )->update( [
            'callback_url' => $url,
        ] );

    }

    return $token;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to cast $request->callback_url to array like this :

```
(array)$request->callback_url
```